# How to create a bash script with optional parameters for a flag

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to create a script which will have a flag with optional options. With getopts it's possible to specify a mandatory argument (using a colon) after the flag, but I want to keep it optional.

It will be something like this:

```
./install.sh -a 3
```

or

```
./install.sh -a3
```

where 'a' is the flag and '3' is the optional parameter that follows a.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `getopt` external program allows options to have a single optional argument by adding a double-colon to the option name.

```
# Based on a longer example in getopt-parse.bash, included with
# getopt
TEMP=$(getopt -o a:: -- "$@")
eval set -- "$TEMP"
while true ; do
   case "$1" in
     -a)
        case "$2" in 
          "") echo "Option a, no argument"; shift 2 ;;
          *) echo "Option a, argument $2"; shift 2;;
        esac ;;
     --) shift; break ;;
     *) echo "Internal error!"; exit 1 ;;
   esac
done
```

Comment: Executing: `./install.sh -a 3` gives "option a, no argment" but the argument is "3"

Comment: `getopt` does not seem to allow a space between an option and its optional argument.

Comment: From `man getopt`: "If the option has an optional argument, it must be written directly after the option character if present."

Answer (score 2):

The following is without `getopt` and it takes an optional argument with the -a flag:

```
for WORD; do
        case $WORD in
            -a?)  echo "single arg Option"
                SEP=${WORD:2:1}
                echo $SEP
                shift ;;
            -a) echo "split arg Option"
                if [[ ${2:0:1} != "-" && ${2:0:1} != ""]] ; then
                 SEP=$2
                 shift 2
                 echo "arg present"
                 echo $SEP
                else
                 echo "optional arg omitted"
                fi ;;
            -a*) echo "arg Option"
                SEP=${WORD:2}
                echo $SEP
                shift ;;
            -*) echo "Unrecognized Short Option"
                echo "Unrecognized argument"
            ;;
        esac
done
```

Other options/flags also can be added easily.

Comment: Indeed, outer `case` was not required. edited that. thanks @l0b0

Comment: Nit: `in "$@"` is not required. `for WORD; do` will loop over the arguments.

Answer (score -1):

Use the getopt feature.  On most systems, `man getopt` will yield documentation for it, and even examples of using it in a script.  From the man page on my system:

The following code fragment shows how one might process the arguments
     for a command that can take the options -a and -b, and the option -o,
     which requires an argument.

```
       args=`getopt abo: $*`
       # you should not use `getopt abo: "$@"` since that would parse
       # the arguments differently from what the set command below does.
       if [ $? != 0 ]
       then
               echo 'Usage: ...'
               exit 2
       fi
       set -- $args
       # You cannot use the set command with a backquoted getopt directly,
       # since the exit code from getopt would be shadowed by those of set,
       # which is zero by definition.
       for i
       do
               case "$i"
               in
                       -a|-b)
                               echo flag $i set; sflags="${i#-}$sflags";
                               shift;;
                       -o)
                               echo oarg is "'"$2"'"; oarg="$2"; shift;
                               shift;;
                       --)
                               shift; break;;
               esac
       done
       echo single-char flags: "'"$sflags"'"
       echo oarg is "'"$oarg"'"
```

This code will accept any of the following as equivalent:

```
       cmd -aoarg file file
       cmd -a -o arg file file
       cmd -oarg -a file file
       cmd -a -oarg -- file file
```

Comment: `getopt` is the right answer, but your long example doesn't demonstrate how to implement an option whose argument is also optional.

Comment: This will break if your arguments contain whitespace. [Example solution.](https://github.com/l0b0/unrarr/blob/master/unrarr.sh#L63-L65)

Comment: Getting down-voted because the content of a standard man page isn't to your liking.  Good times on SO.

Comment: Or because it doesn't answer OP and contains bugs.

Answer (score -1):

In bash there is some implicit variable:

```
    $#: contains number of arguments for a called script/function

    $0: contains names of script/function
    $1: contains first argument
    $2: contains second argument
    ...
    $n: contains n-th argument
```

For example:

```
    #!/bin/ksh

    if [ $# -ne 2 ]
    then
        echo "Wrong number of argument - expected 2 : $#"
    else
        echo "Argument list:"
        echo "\t$0"
        echo "\t$1"
        echo "\t$2"
    fi
```

Comment: The question asks how to define an option whose argument is also optional.

Comment: yeah, and i prefer explain to him how to catch an argument than give him a full answer. Sometime its better for someone to find the way by himself... Btw your answe deserve a -1 because of your "while true"...

Comment: @binogure `while true` is not wrong in and of itself -- there needs to be a terminating condition, but that can be a `break`.

Comment: I initially left out the terminating `break` while trying to simplify the example that ships with `getopt`.

Comment: I guess you meant `#!/bin/bash` ;)

Answer (score -1):

My solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
skip=0
flag="no flag"
list=($@) #put args in array
for arg in $@ ; do #iterate over array
    count=$(($count+1)) #update counter
    if [ $skip -eq 1 ]; then #check if we have to skip this args
        skip=0
        continue
    fi
    opt=${arg:0:2} #get only first 2 chars as option
    if [ $opt == "-a" ]; then #check if option equals "-a"
       if [ $opt == $arg ] ; then #check if this is only the option or has a flag
            if [ ${list[$count]:0:1} != "-" ]; then #check if next arg is an option
                skip=1 #skip next arg
                flag=${list[$count]} #use next arg as flag
            fi
       else
            flag=${arg:2} #use chars after "-a" as flag
       fi 
    fi
done

echo $flag
```

Comment: `in $@` is superfluous. Also, POSIX `sh` doesn't have arrays. `==` is not portable.

Comment: @l0b0 why is `in $@` superfluous? It could be substituded by `$list` but is needed. I agree the code is not portable and I changed the header to `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Because `for arg` will iterate over `"$@"` by default.